# Automatically create more VM's on certain CPU utilization on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, load-balancing

I currently have a setup on GCP where there is a VM (main) which receives client requests and then store some data based on those requests on a DB inside it.

Then, on the side, I have another VM (worker) which just "listens" (or checks) if there's an entry in the DB of the main VM. If there's an entry, it takes that entry and processes it.

The main VM is basically just the "gatekeeper" which receives the requests but the worker VM is the one that does most of the work.

I want to create more worker VM's when the worker VM hits a certain CPU utilization. I've already explored GCP's Load Balancer but I have no idea if this is the right thing because the worker VM isn't really accepting any requests; it just works on its own.

Do you have any idea how to I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use managed instance groups.

[This page](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances) describes how to create a managed instance group (MIG). MIGs support features such as autohealing, load balancing, autoscaling, auto-updating, and stateful workloads.

MIGs support autoscaling that dynamically adds or removes instances from the MIG in response to increases or decreases in load.

Use the [`set-autoscaling`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instance-groups/managed/set-autoscaling) sub-command to enable autoscaling for a managed instance group.

For example, the following command creates an autoscaler that has a target CPU utilization of 60%. Along with the `--target-cpu-utilization` parameter, the `--max-num-replicas` parameter is also required when creating an autoscaler:

```
gcloud compute instance-groups managed set-autoscaling example-managed-instance-group \
    --max-num-replicas 5 \
    --target-cpu-utilization 0.60 \
    --cool-down-period 90
```

You can learn more about how to create a managed instance group in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/creating-groups-of-managed-instances#create_managed_group).

Or you can follow these steps:

1. In the Cloud Console, go to the [**Instance groups** page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instanceGroups?_ga=2.104834053.406812832.1600698248-638966553.1591892739).
2. Click **Create an instance group**.
3. Enter a name for the MIG, and select the zone where you want to locate the group.
4. Under **Group type**, select **Managed instance group.**
5. Under **Instance template**, select an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates). If no templates are available, [create an instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates).
6. Specify the number of instances that you want to create in the group. Optionally, enable **Autoscaling** so that the group [automatically adds or removes instances](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler) based on its utilization, or enable [autohealing](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-groups/autohealing-instances-in-migs) to perform application-based health checking on VMs within the group.
7. Click **Create** to create the new group.

As you can see you can set the autoscaler when you create your MIG.

Please check the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/autoscaler/scaling-cpu#scaling_based_on_cpu_utilization) for more information about Scaling based on CPU utilization.